# What is the appropriate English language terminology for referring to the object in C++?

Tags: c++, terminology

What is the correct / appropriate English terminology for referring to the "current" object in C++.  For example, say you are writing a comment in the body of the implementation of this:

```
Thing Thing::operator+(const Thing& other)
```

You have the variable name "other" to use for the other object, but what word / expression do you use to refer to the object that is doing the operation?

Comment: Just a bit of nit-pickery, but operator +() should almost certainly be implemented as a free function, in which case there is no "current" object.

Comment: I usually use `rhs` and not `other`, because it's the right-hand side object and this meshes easily with the `lhs` vs `rhs` that I use for free functions later on.

Answer (score 11):

In C++ it's called `this` object and that's what I'm using.

***Edit***: I second Neil's comment about `operator+()` better being a non-member. For me, the canonical form is to implement `+=` as a member (it changes the left-hand side object and should thus have access to it) and implement `operator+` on top of it:

```
inline Thing operator+(Thing lhs, const Thing& rhs)
{
  lhs += rhs;
  return lhs;
}
```

(Note: I used to pass `lhs` by const reference, too, and perform the copying within the function, but got convinced a while ago that it's better to pass it as a copy instead.)

Comment: And people discovered the Boost.operators library :D Not only do you write less, but it even enforces this particular behavior.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with "this" is that it is a common word in English. As someone that has lectured extensively on C++, I always found it difficult when speaking to get across when I was using "this" to mean the current object. I never came up with a perfect solution, but often wished that BS had used "self" instead of "this".

Comment: "the this pointer" is a bit more explicit, but yeah, hardly ideal.

Comment: And it's even worse: the questioner isn't talking about "the this pointer", he's talking about "the referand of the this pointer".

Comment: true. Would've been nice if it'd been called "self" rather than "this", and been an actual reference instead of a pointer.

Comment: @jalf: It would have been nice, but he added `this` before he added references, and by then it was well established and would have been hard to change.

Comment: At least in comments, I find `*this` fairly explicit -- the asterisk makes it fairly clear that I'm not just using "this" in its normal English language sense, and it explicitly refers to the object pointed to by``this`, rather than to the `this` pointer itself.

Comment: @Jerry: Actually, I have used `*this`, too, and I did it for the same reason.

Answer (score 3):

Either "this", or maybe "this instance". As in:

```
/** \brief Adds another Thing to this instance.
 * A reference to this instance is returned.
*/
Thing& Thing::operator+(const Thing& other);
```

The markup is [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/), for those not familiar with that.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to use the same convention in documentation as I use in code: I leave it implicit. E.g. "Add another thing and return the sum".

When I need to be explicit, it's for comments read by other programmers. They know C++, `*this` is easily understood. E.g. "Add another Thing to `*this` by adding all members except Thing::foo which will become 0 (See bug #42)"

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's `this` pointer specifically for that purpose. Therefore it's only natural to refer to the current object as "this object".

Answer (score 2):

Could also use "left operand" and "right operand", since your operator is binary.

Answer (score 0):

In comments, I usually say either "this" or "ourself" (because I generally write comments in first-person plural, but "ourselves" is too weird when there's only one object).

In documentation, I say "the `<whatever>`". If that's ambiguous (because the function takes another one as a parameter, for instance), I say "this object", or "this `<whatever>`". `<whatever>` is either the class name, or some other term used in the documentation to explain what the class represents.

```
/**
 * An utterly useless write-only counter, with arbitrary initial value.
 */
class Counter {
    unsigned int count;
public:
    /** 
     * Increments the counter
     */
    Counter &operator++() {
        // We need to add 1 to ourself. I found a snippet online that does it:
        ++count;
        // return ourself
        return *this;
    }
    /**
     * Adds together this counter and "other".
     */
    Counter operator+(const Counter &other) const {
        Counter result;
        // new count is our count plus other count
        result.count = count + other.count;
        return result;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you implement an operator outside of the class scope, then the arguments are often named `lhs` and `rhs` (left-hand side and right-hand side).

You don't really need a name for the current object, because you already have the `this`pointer. Inside static methods a pointer an object of the class is sometimes needed (for example to call an instance method). In those situations I use the variable name `pThis`.

If you do need a name when speaking about it, then "self" makes sense. I sometimes refer to it as "the this object".

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that if you want to refer to the current object, you can't really go wrong calling it **the current object**.

Comment: And then maybe you can. "The current object" to me (a non-native, so I might be wrong) implies a timespan while it is the current. However, during the same timespan, `other` is just as current.

Answer (score -2):

There is **no current object in C++** , but only **pointer to object** avalilable in the member function is **this pointer** .

Comment: While that is technically correct; it's not a particularly helpful way at looking at an object-oriented language.

Comment: Uh, yes, there **is** a current object. What do you think `this` is pointing at?